# Executing Batch script Asyncronously from Dot Net MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, console-application, async-await

I have a dot net MVC 4 application in which I user creates a request using "create" view and based on the params from view, the controller should execute windows batch scripts asynchronously.

I'm using following code to run the batch script:

```
Process process = new Process();

ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c  batchfile");
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
ProcessInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", arg1, arg2, arg3); ;

process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
```

The console app process is started but it always hangs/waits endlessly. The standard output logs show:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>
```

The process exits only when I manually kill it. I tried running Visual Studio administrator mode but it didn't help.

Can anyone please suggest how I can get around this?

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous in your code.

Comment: Code snippet that I have added is part of the function which I call asynchronously. As the batch file executes some file I/O operations that take time. I thought I'm missing something on the MVC side, but it ended up as problem in passing arguments to cmd.exe from c# code

Comment: Why are you calling it asynchronously when you then block waiting for the process to exit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [reference article](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) about command line parameters passed to `cmd.exe` I would recommend you checking.

Then try like this:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
{
    Arguments = string.Format("/k \"\"batchfile.bat\" \"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"\"", arg1, arg2, arg3),
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};

using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. As suggested by you, it was indeed problem of spaces in batch file path which I was passing as argument.